# How to define element size with ToBoundaryMesh?

Tags: mesh, finite-element-method

I am trying to make a mesh for finite element analysis with shell elements: I have to define 2D finite elements in 3D space. My code is:

```
mesh = ToBoundaryMesh[Polygon[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {2, 0, 0}, {2, 0, 0.2}, {0, 0, 0.2}}], "MaxBoundaryCellMeasure" -> 0.01];
```

However, the produced mesh does not seem to consider the prescribed "MaxBoundaryCellMeasure", since the result is the same regardless the prescribed value for "MaxBoundaryCellMeasure":

[image]

Is this possibly a bug? I can solve the problem for the presented simple case with other possible definitions of my domain (e.g. ImplicitRegion). However, I would like to be able to prescribe mesh density when I define domain as Polygon, since I will have to define some more complex domains (with imperfect holes etc.)

Thank you in advance for the answer!

Comment: I gues the problem here is that your mesh does not describe a boundary of a 3-dimensional domain so that `TetGenLink` cannot be used to refine it. Instead, you could set up this mesh in the plane first (e.g., with `ToElementMesh`), then extract the coordinates and cells, map the coordinates to $\mathbb{R}^3$, and then apply `ToBoundaryMesh`.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is seems to be a short coming of `ToBoundaryMesh`. But you can work abound that with:

```
dg = DiscretizeRegion[
   Polygon[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {2, 0, 0}, {2, 0, 0.2}, {0, 0, 
      0.2}}], MaxCellMeasure -> {"Area" -> 0.005}];
ToBoundaryMesh[dg]["Wireframe"]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Henrik Schumacher and user21. You've solve my problem and now it works fine!